# Shared Preferences in Objective C from Android

Tags: android, objective-c, arrays, sharedpreferences, nsuserdefaults

Is there anyway to re-create this code into Objective c? I am just starting out, and I need some help.

```
String name = #;// Will often vary.

SharedPreferences userData = this.getSharedPreferences(name + "userdata", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor edit = userData.edit();
    edit.clear();
    edit.putFloat("rating", Rating.getRating());
    edit.putString("good", txtGood.getText().toString().trim());
    edit.putString("improve", txtImprove.getText().toString().trim());
    edit.commit();
    Log.d(TAG, "Saving Data");
```

The advantage of this code is that is makes a new SharedPreference everytime the method is called. With my experience using NSUserDefaults, it was only able to make 1 batch of data.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/ please look at this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSString*)GetFilePath:(NSString*)filename
{
     NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString* file = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@.plist",filename];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"plist"]; //5

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error]; //6
    }  
    return path;
}
```

and call like this from any method:

```
NSMutableDictionary* TempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self GetFilePath:@"FileName"]];
```

Plist is like sharedpreferences where you can save anykind of data. arrays,strings,booleans etc and also there is no limit to that. you can take look at [this](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/) for more info.

Comment: Is there anyway to dynamically declare variables in the .plist file?

Comment: ofcourse it is. Keys are always dynamic. you can use key names for dynamic purpose.

Answer (score 6):

`NSUserDefaults`(Objective-C) are similar to `SharedPreferences`(Android).

```
   // To save data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"title" forKey:@"kTitle"];
    [defaults setInteger:21 forKey:@"kSrNo"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Data are saved to defaults.");

   // To retrive it back
    NSString *title = [defaults objectForKey:@"kTitle"];
    int srno = [defaults integerForKey:@"kSrNo"];
    NSLog(@"Data from defaults--> Title: %@ SrNO: %d",title,srno);
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my post because I wasn't clear enough. Thanks for your answer anyway.